# Get Reddit user comments using PRAW causing TypeError: 'SubListing' object is not callable error

Tags: python, praw

I'm trying to retrieve the last 1000 comments from a user since 1000 is the Reddit limit.

I followed the code example [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/1n7164/can_i_get_all_comments_of_a_user_by_calling/ccfyhp8/), and modified a few of the calls for the updated API. Such as user.get_comments now seems to be just user.comments.

Here is the code I've run.

```
import praw

my_user_agent = 'USERAGENT'
my_client_id = 'CLIENTID'
my_client_secret = 'SECRET'

r = praw.Reddit(user_agent=my_user_agent,
                     client_id=my_client_id,
                     client_secret=my_client_secret)

user = r.redditor('REDDITUSERNAME')

for comment in user.comments(limit=None):
    print comment.body
```

I get an error every time on the last line, though.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'SubListing' object is not callable
```

I have connected to the API and have an active connection as I can do print(user.comment_karma) and it displays correctly.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't use code format for error log, [meta question about that](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276966/quote-formatting-messing-up-how-to-handle-format-of-error-logs).

Comment: @Stargateur Thanks for the catch. Edited the question as per the meta post.

Comment: Are you using PRAW 3 or 4? I believe the API may have changed a little bit since that example.

Comment: Just a stab in the dark but why do you have just user.comments instead of user.get_comments?

Comment: @Aurora0001 PRAW 4.

Comment: @jeffcarey As of PRAW 4.0 (possibly earlier I'm not sure) get_comments isn't a valid call as it's been replaced with just comments. A lot of the calls that previously used get_something now use just .something

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the documentation, [`comments`](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/redditor.html#praw.models.Redditor.comments) is an **attribute** of the `Redditor` model in PRAW 4, not a function. Therefore, calling `.comments(limit=None)` is invalid syntax because `.comments` isn't a function. Instead, you must specify a **listing sort order**, like so, because `SubListing` objects (what `user.comments` is) inherit from [`BaseListingMixin`](https://github.com/praw-dev/praw/blob/praw4/praw/models/listing/mixins/base.py#L16):

```
for comment in user.comments.new():
    print(comment.body)
```

Admittedly, the documentation for PRAW 4 is very unclear, and you'll probably find the best documentation by searching through the code directly.

Comment: That's odd, the property [definitely exists](https://github.com/praw-dev/praw/blob/praw4/praw/models/listing/mixins/redditor.py#L13). Does `user = r.redditor('REDDITUSERNAME')` help in any way? (instead of `get_redditor`)

Comment: Sorry forgot to change that in the code. It is now just r.redditor rather than r.get_redditor, and that is what I'm using I just copy and pasted the code block before fixing that error. I've edited the code in the question now.

Comment: Thanks that solved it, although it isn't displaying the full 1000 comment history is should by default - that's what the (limit=none) part did. Any ideas how to add that in if you say it's invalid syntax.

Comment: @TheBeginningEnd that *should* be valid for the `.new()` function (i.e. `user.comments.new(limit=None)` should work) but just not for `.comments(limit=None)` which is invalid.

Comment: Perfect. I've marked the answer as correct and upvoted it, but because of my karma score the upvote won't show yet.

Comment: @TheBeginningEnd you'll get this privilege at 15 rep (you can get 2 more rep points by editing someone's post to improve it) and then you'll have to re-upvote everything (the upvotes aren't actually remembered). Glad it helped you though - PRAW's docs seem really scarce at the minute.

Comment: @Aurora0001 I added some examples to the documentation. I hope you find them useful: https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/other/sublisting.html#praw.models.listing.mixins.redditor.SubListing.new

Comment: @bboe very helpful, thanks. I appreciate the work you're doing with PRAW 4!